# JS: what's a use-case of Promise.resolve()

Tags: javascript

I am looking at https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/ and it mentions it can be used if you need a value in the form of a promise like:

```
var value = 10;
var promiseForValue = Promise.resolve(value);
```

What would be the use of a value in promise form though since it would run synchronously anyway?

If I had:

```
var value = 10;
var promiseForValue = Promise.resolve(value);

promiseForValue.then(resp => {
   myFunction(resp)
})
```

wouldn't just using value without it being a Promise achieve the same thing:

```
 var value = 10;
 myFunction(10);
```

Comment: You might also ask, why do you need the empty string? Or why you need the empty array? Or why you need the number 0? By themselves, the values are frankly quite useless, but they act as a building block that you can add/append/chain promises onto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your examples, yes, there's no point in calling `Promise.resolve(value)`. The use case is when you do want to wrap your already existing value in a Promise, for example to maintain the same API from a function. Let's say I have a function that conditionally does something that would return a promise — the caller of that function shouldn't be the one figuring out what the function returned, the function itself should just make that uniform. For example:

```
const conditionallyDoAsyncWork = (something) =>  {
  if (something == somethingElse) {
    return Promise.resolve(false)
  }

  return fetch(`/foo/${something}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
}
```

Then users of this function don't need to check if what they got back was a Promise or not:

```
const doSomethingWithData = () => {
  conditionallyDoAsyncWork(someValue)
    .then((result) => result && processData(result))
}
```

As a side node, using async/await syntax both hides that and makes it a bit easier to read, because any value you return from an `async` function is automatically wrapped in a Promise:

```
const conditionallyDoAsyncWork = async (something) =>  {
  if (something == somethingElse) {
    return false
  }

  const res = await  fetch(`/foo/${something}`)
  return res.json()
}

const doSomethingWithData = async () => {
  const result = await conditionallyDoAsyncWork(someValue)
  if (result) processData(result)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Say if you write a function that *sometimes* fetches something from a server, but other times immediately returns, you will probably want that function to always return a promise:

```js
function myThingy() {
  if (someCondition) {
    return fetch('https://foo');
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

It's also useful if you receive some value that *may or may not be* a promise. You can wrap it in other promise, and now you are sure it's a promise:

```js
const myValue = someStrangeFunction();

// Guarantee that myValue is a promise
Promise.resolve(myValue).then( ... );
```

Answer (score 2):

Another use case: dead simple async queue using `Promise.resolve()` as starting point.

```
let current = Promise.resolve();

function enqueue(fn) {
    current = current.then(fn);
}

enqueue(async () => { console.log("async task") });
```

---

### Edit, in response to OP's question.

#### Explanation

Let me break it down for you step by step.

`enqueue(task)` add the task function as a callback to `promise.then`, and replace the original `current` promise reference with the newly returned `thenPromise`.

```js
current = Promise.resolve()
thenPromise = current.then(task)
current = thenPromise
```

As per promise spec, if `task` function in turn returns yet another promise, let's call it `task() -> taskPromise`, well then the `thenPromise` will only resolve when `taskPromise` resolves. `thenPromise` is practically equivalent to `taskPromise`, it's just a wrapper. Let's rewrite above code into:

```js
current = Promise.resolve()
taskPromise = current.then(task)
current = taskPromise
```

So if you go like:

```
enqueue(task_1)
enqueue(task_2)
enqueue(task_3)
```

it expands into

```
current = Promise.resolve()
task_1_promise = current.then(task_1)
task_2_promise = task_1_promise.then(task_2)
task_3_promise = task_2_promise.then(task_3)
current = task_3_promise
```

effectively forms a linked-list-like struct of promises that'll execute task callbacks in sequential order.

---

#### Usage

Let's study a concrete scenario. Imaging you need to handle websocket messages in sequential order.

Let's say you need to do some heavy computation upon receiving messages, so you decide to send it off to a worker thread pool. Then you write the processed result to another message queue (MQ).

But here's the requirement, that MQ is expecting the writing order of messages to match with the order they come in from the websocket stream. What do you do?

Suppose you cannot pause the websocket stream, you can only handle them locally ASAP.

#### Take One:

```js
websocket.on('message', (msg) => {
  sendToWorkerThreadPool(msg).then(result => {    
    writeToMessageQueue(result)
  })
})
```

This may violate the requirement, cus `sendToWorkerThreadPool` may not return the result in the original order since it's a pool, some threads may return faster if the workload is light.

#### Take Two:

```js
websocket.on('message', (msg) => {
  const task = () => sendToWorkerThreadPool(msg).then(result => {    
    writeToMessageQueue(result)
  })
  enqueue(task)
})
```

This time we enqueue (defer) the whole process, thus we can ensure the task execution order stays sequential. But there's a drawback, we lost the benefit of using a thread pool, cus each `sendToWorkerThreadPool` will only fire after last one complete. This model is equivalent to using a single worker thread.

#### Take Three:

```js
websocket.on('message', (msg) => {
  const promise = sendToWorkerThreadPool(msg)
  const task = () => promise.then(result => {    
    writeToMessageQueue(result)
  })
  enqueue(task)
})
```

Improvement over take two is, we call `sendToWorkerThreadPool` ASAP, without deferring, but we still enqueue/defer the `writeToMessageQueue` part. This way we can make full use of thread pool for computation, but still ensure the sequential writing order to MQ.

I rest my case.